# Transient analysis of a step RL circuit

Tags: capacitor, resistors, inductor

[image]

In the above problem for t>0 the inductor can be modelled as a short circuit and therefore the current flowing through it is -4/8 or -0.5 A, as no current flows through the 4 ohm resistor. But to determine the Thevenin equivalent resistance as seen through the inductor the 4 ohm resistor must be considered as being in parallel with an 8 ohm resistor, so that the Thevenin equivalent resistance is 8/3 ohms. But if no current flows through the resistor, V = 0*R = 0 and R*0 = 0 so R can have any value, so why is a value of 4 ohms used to calculate the Thevenin equivalent resistance? Is this because the inductor must be viewed as a load rather than as a short circuit and the result is independent of whether an inductor or another element is connected, or because Ohm's law does not apply or I am interpreting it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

It is true that the voltage across the 4 ohm resistor is zero because ideally no current flows through it if there’s a short across it. However in reality there would be a small but practically negligible current through the 4 ohms but will assume it’s ideally nothing. This doesn’t mean that the 4 ohms has no current flow when the switch is turned to location B. Therefore we must include 4 ohm in the calculation thevenin resistance and thus to determine the of time constant.